# Javascript reduce to produce a total cost not working

Tags: javascript, reduce

I'm attempting to output a total cost based off the totals but can't seem to get this functioning as intended with the .reduce method.

I build a "costs" array up which looks like this:

```
const costs = ["5.50", "1.00", "2.00", "1.50"]
```

I then attempt to assign a variable called totalCost to the totals (have tried various ways with the parseFloat().toFixed(2) methods but not having the desired outcome.

```
// Returns prev is not defined (2nd instance)
const totalCost = costs.reduce((prev, current, index) => prev, parseFloat(prev + current).toFixed(2), 0);

// Returns prev is not defined due to mismatch of values associated to the arguments
const totalCost = costs.reduce((prev, current, index) => prev + parseFloat(current).toFixed(2), 0);
```

The result is always either 5.50 (the first value in the array) or a string which attaches them all.

Have also tried forEach. and a straight + of the values with a parseFloat().toFixed(2)

Any points in the right direction would be appreciated as I feel it's almost there, but I've been banging my head against a wall for the last hour or so.

Comment: Don't use `toFixed()` as part of the `reduce()` call. Call it at the end: `costs.reduce((p, c) => p + parseFloat(c), 0).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem with your first attempt
`costs.reduce((prev, current, index) => prev, parseFloat(prev + current).toFixed(2), 0);`

is that the language has no way of distinguishing the comma on `prev,` as the end of the function or the end of the argument. It thus thinks `parseFloat...` is the next argument to your reduce function.

Your second issue is that `toFixed` returns a *string*.

How about:

```js
costs.reduce((prev, current, index) => prev + parseFloat(current), 0).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and makes perfect sense.  
I can confirm that works and will accept as the answer shortly.